# Navigation Back and Forward not working at Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij IDEA and Navigation Back(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>) and
 Forward(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>) not working (tried in version 14 & 15), 
but settings seems to be okey. How to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Works for me. What system are you on? Maybe some global system shortcut is interfering with Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right

Comment: I am using Windows 7 enterprise. Intel Graphics has the same shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right) for rotating the screen. I disabled it, but still I am not able to navigate to Back/Forward.

Comment: In my case it is Microsoft Remote Destop which intercepts these combinations.  I had to assign new shortcuts (alt-[ and alt-]) to these functions.

Comment: Another issue is that ok, the shortcut is working, but it is not doing what I would expect. If I CTRL-click on some method, it shows it, now I want to go back. Issue navigate back, but it goes way back somewhere else, instead of the previous location from where I CTRL-click. Is this an expected behavior, or something is broken?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Intel Graphics uses these hotkeys for rotating the screen(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> are used to rotate the screen 90 degree Left/Right). I have disabled Graphics hotkey, but still I was not able to use these hotkey in Intellij IDEA, then I changed the hotkey for Intel Graphics(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>). Now I am able to Navigate Back and Forward with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Comment: How/Where did you change the Intel graphics hotkey?

Comment: Hotkeys settings you can find in options of 'graphic options' application (or something similar)- which you can open using ctrl+alt+F12 or rightclick on desktop and select 'Graphics options'.

Comment: Another way is to simply disable the hotkeys. RIght click on desktop>Graphics options>Hot keys>Disable.

Comment: Another layer of trickiness for VMware Workstation 12 Pro users (and likely other versions of VMware Workstation) is the default key combination for VMware special commands is Ctrl+Alt. This can be rebound from Edit>Preferences>Hotkeys

Comment: Did not work for me, i disabled all intel shortcuts and still can't navigate

Comment: So many users so often rotates their screens so these hotkeys must be enabled by default. >:-)

Comment: @sam Please read my answer. it will not work even if you disable the hotkeys. You have to change to some other key

Comment: @AmareshNarayanan Disabling did not work and changing shortcuts didn't help, too.

Comment: I had System/HotKeys disabled, but still Command Center was stealing keystrokes. I solved it by pressing "Reset to Original Settings" and disabling hot keys again. Hope it helps others too.

Comment: In my fresh new computer, for some unknown reason there are two applications: _Control panel for UHD Intel graphics_ with lightblue design and _Control center of Intel graphics_ with darkblue-black design. (Translation guessed by me, original names are Czech _Ovládací panel pro UHD grafiku Intel_ and _Ovládací centrum grafiky Intel_.) **Only the second one does the trick.** In System -> Shortcuts I had shortcuts _Disabled_ but Idea didn't work anyway. Enabling and disabling back is enough to make Idea work.

Comment: Intel Graphics has changed to Intel Command Center dated Oct 9 2020 Windows 10

Comment: desktop->right click of any corner->graphics options->hot keys->disable/enable

Comment: Followed everything, still not working for me. :(

I am using RDP to connect to my dev box, which doesn't have any hotkeys settings. I have disabled them on my laptop.

Answer (score 29):

In Gnome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> are bound to `switch-to-workspace-left/right` per default.
To remove these keybindings, call:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']"
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"
```

Answer (score 19):

Still applicable in 2020...
What worked for me was to not only disable the Intel Graphics system hotkeys, but to enable them first, change them to something that is not currently in use and then disable them back.
Simply disabling them did not work for me.

Comment: Same here: open up the start menu > type "Intel" to find an entry to open the app > System > Turn hotkeys on, then off again

Comment: solution in first comment works for me thank you!!!

Comment: same here! 
any explanation what might cause this weird behaviour?

Comment: + one more from 2020. It was disabled as I already was facing this issue some time ago. But it came again.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to opens Intel `control panel`. 
Go to options and disable hot keys.

**Note:** If you need to enable hot keys back (<kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> will not work), go to Start menu in Windows paste Intel Graphics and run one of these files: `Gfxv4_0.exe`, `GfxUIEx.exe`, `Gfxv2_0.exe`. Intel Graphics

Answer (score 5):

You can solve the problem without hacking systemwide keymap.
In IntelliJ go to **File > Settings > Keymap** in which you can assign keyboard/mouse shortcuts into actions.

Also you can choose from other existing keymaps for example Gnome if you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: This is the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Tagging onto Amaresh Narayanan's answer. I also had to **change** the hotkeys as disabling alone did not work (changed screen rotation to `ctrl+alt+8` and `ctrl+alt+9`, just something that is hard to mistype).

My fix was to go into Intel Command Center and change the hotkeys.

Beware that  `ctrl+alt+f12` lead me to the OLD Intel's settings manager on Windows. At the time of writing, there's Intel Command Center and Intel Control Panel, the latter of which editing the settings did not work and was the shortcut `ctrl+alt+f12`.

Comment: This worked for me specially since I didn't know that Intal has changed the name to Intel Command Center and you can't go in there from Right Clicking the Desktop ... Kudos !

Comment: Saved days of frustration

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Desktop => Graphic Options => Hot Keys => Disable

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> instead.

Comment: Please add some more explanation, it looks more like a comment.

Comment: For Ubuntu/Pop-OS this solved my problem. The Ctr+Alt+Left/Right does not work, but Shift+Alt+Left/Right does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use, backward/forward command in intellij. you have to disable hot keys.

> desktop->right click of any corner->graphics options->hot keys->disable/enable

Answer (score 0):

A potential cause for this can also be VMware Workstation. Its default key combination for special VM commands is <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>. This will override any hotkeys that involve <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> on the virtualized system. The key combination can be rebound from Edit>Preferences>Hotkeys.

My specific version of VMware workstation is 12 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Xubuntu, open [Window Manager], go to [keyboard], and remove/change the key combination for [Left Workspace] and [Right Workspace]. This will allow Intellij to use the hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

In the Case of Mac, Go To

Preferences -> KeyMap -> Main Menu -> Navigate

Change Back & Forward to the shortcuts you prefer

Answer (score 0):

The most recent solution is to update the Intel Graphics Command Center version and then disable hotkeys:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057495/graphics/graphics-for-10th-generation-intel-processors.html

What are you seeing?
Applications such as PHPStorm* and JetBrains* have their Ctrl + Alt hotkeys disabled after installing the Intel® Graphics Command Center for the first time.

How to fix it:
This issue is resolved in Intel® Graphics Command Center version 1.100.2970.0 and newer. Install the latest version of the Intel® Graphics Command Center in the Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody happens to use awesomewm its default configuration is using MPD plugin which steals Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right shortcuts. Check your rc.lua configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it because windows remote desktop did't send this shortkey to remote pc.You can check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/327866/remote-desktop-sending-ctrl-alt-left-arrow-ctrl-alt-right-arrow-to-the-remote-p)

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ you can update the settings from View -> Appearance and select "Toolbar", then you will get the button which can be used to go back and forward.

[IntelliJ Settings to update button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11QQq.png)